# Azure storage replication vs Azure Backup

Tags: azure, azure-backup-vault

Why do we need Azure backup for our VMs (disks) on azure, when azure storage account provides different replication options like LRS, ZRS, GRS, RA-GRS.

All the data is already replicate in different region (in case of GRS), what advantes I will get out of Azure Backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> All the data is already replicate in different region (in case of
>   GRS), what advantes I will get out of Azure Backup.

Replication is not backup!

It is true that when you opt for GRS replication, 6 copies of your data is maintained (3 in primary and 3 in secondary) but when you delete the data from primary, data from secondary is automatically deleted.

**UPDATE**

> You mean, if any data is deleted/corrupted due to some error/bug, can
>   be reproduced from backup and it is not possible in case of storage
>   replication.

You're absolutely correct!

> But Microsoft sells "Azure backup and Site recovery" as a BCDR
>   strategy. In context of any disaster, why not just rely on Storage
>   replication. Any advantages of Azure backup/site recovery?

I have not used Azure backup so let me answer it from Storage Replication point of view. To put things simply, "In context of Azure, a disaster is not a disaster unless Microsoft thinks it is a disaster". Till the time that happens, you don't get access to secondary assuming you have opted for GRS replication (with RA-GRS, you obviously have an option to read the data from secondary at all times).

Furthermore if you choose LRS or Premium LRS replication and there's indeed a disaster in one data center, all of your data will be lost. With Azure Backup, you at least have a copy of your data lying somewhere safe and you could recreate your environment based on that backup.

Comment: thanks for reply! i understood your point. You mean, if any data is deleted/corrupted due to some error/bug, can be reproduced from backup and it is not possible in case of storage replication. But Microsoft sells "Azure backup and Site recovery" as a BCDR strategy. In context of any disaster, why not just rely on Storage replication. Any advantages of Azure backup/site recovery?

Comment: Let me update my answer with comments to your questions.

Comment: I got your point, but technically, there must be a solid reason on going for Azure backup over storage replication.

Comment: I would let someone experienced with Azure Backup chime in. But one more reason I could think of is point in time restore functionality. You could have multiple backups taken over a period of time which is just not possible with storage replication.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but MS provide a solution for Disaster recovery by Storage account

We may have 2 solution for dealing with Disaster

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-disaster-recovery-guidance?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

it said :

If the primary endpoint becomes unavailable for any reason, the client is no longer able to write to the storage account. The following image shows the scenario where the primary has become unavailable, but no recovery has happened yet:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZJQG.png)

The customer initiates the account failover to the secondary endpoint. The failover process updates the DNS entry provided by Azure Storage so that the secondary endpoint becomes the new primary endpoint for your storage account, as shown in the following image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnT3Z.png)